# Creating/updating schema from Doctrine entities

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine with Zend Framework. I have to create both the DB schema and the Doctrine entities with annotations.

Since the annotations already contain the information, it should be possible to create/update the schema based on them. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I was wondering whether that kind of logic already existed?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the doctrine CLI, for a lot of doctrine related tasks. I'm not sure how doctrine is integrated into Zend, but look for the doctrine.php, and invoke it like this:

```
php doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

This will update your db to match your schema definitions. You can also use

```
php doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql
```

To see what SQL commands would doctrine run. See the [Tools section](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/tools.html#doctrine-console) in the doctrine docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There's the Doctrine SchemaTool (ORM/Tools/SchemaTool).

```
$meta = array(
    $this->_em->getClassMetadata('Customer')
);

$tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($this->_em);
$tool->updateSchema($meta);
```

Comment: You should give credit to the original answerer, and before posting his answer, you should have asked him to do so by himself

Comment: I do like the fact it's CW. However, attribution is still needed.

Comment: @JanDvorak What do you mean by attribution? (Other than marking it as CW that is.) Do you mean writing in the answer body who wrote it first? Wouldn't that be too meta? Last but not least, I agree that I could have asked the user first yet considering the date of the question I opted against it. Also there is no "mark this question for later edit in case I forget I want to edit". What ever happened to be bold anyway? ;)