# What does --dump-sql do?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine with CodeIgniter. I usually update the database with `orm:schema-tool:update --force`, which makes the database the same as my models. Now I have some sensitive updates and I dont want make any damage to my DB.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7375067/847773). It seems like  `--dump-sql` returns the SQL needed to update the tables, does it also actually update the tables is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not  update the table.

`--dump-sql` just print the SQL and `--force` execute the SQL without printing it.

`--dump-sql` helps you to see what `--force` is going to do exactly.

Comment: To add to your answer, doing `--dump-sql >> filename.sql` in unix dumps it to the file you want. It is pretty useful when you want to control the sql updates, when having both a dev and a prod environment.